# How do I enter data in array from a text file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to populate an array using the data in text file in JavaScript. The data in text file is in the following format:

0.1 0.5
0.2 0.8
0.3 0.7
0.4 0.9
0.5 0.2

and so on..

Comment: [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Questions that show little / minimal effort aren't well received. I suggest you read the FAQ for how to ask a good question.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So many similar questions… look around, do your homework.

Comment: Sorry for that..I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers support opening files in JavaScript through the [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). If you want a more cross-browser solution, you'll have to use a java/swf applet, or you'll need to pass the file to a PHP server and get back its content through AJAX.

Yes, it's that complex to do something as simple as opening a file in JS. It wasn't made for this purpose, and it would be a security issue if JS could easily access any file in your PC.

As for how to parse the data, look at `String.split` like Blazemonger suggested, or learn how to do [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Finally, you could store the file in this format:

```
[0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8]
```

And call `JSON.parse(filecontent)` and it would return an array with the values. JSON is the standard way to store JS objects in files.

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna look into JSON.